# Dividing groups in dataframe by median of separate groups

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing a columns `group_ID` and `class`, and multiple numeric features, and some character metadata, i.e:

```
group_ID  class  var1  var2  var3  metadata
a         foo    1     324   3     cat
a         bar    1.3   34    53    dog
a         baz    31    34    5     elephant
b         foo    34    34    943   dolphin
b         bar    94    51    23    chipmunk
b         baz    985   595   43    badger
c         foo    43    93    23    tapir
c         bar    43    23    23    monkey
c         baz    40    53    512   duck
```

I want to calculate the median of class `foo` for each `group_ID`, and then divide each row by the median that matches the `group_ID`.

In this example I only have 1 row for each `foo`, so the median will be the same as the initial values, but in reality I have many rows for each `class` and `group_ID`.

---

Is there a simple way to do this? My best attempt to far has included creating a separate dataframe for the median values of `foo`, and then splitting by group_ID and sweep in a horrible loop, but I end up losing the metadata column. It seems like quite a routine thing to do so I'm sure I'm missing something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This works for me, but you should add the expected result from this example to be sure `df %>% group_by(group_ID) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(./median(.[class == "bar"])), var1:var3)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `mutate_each` from `dplyr` to divide by the condition.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group_ID) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(./median(.[class == "foo"])), var1:var3)
# Source: local data frame [9 x 6]
# Groups: group_ID
# 
#   group_ID class       var1       var2        var3 metadata
# 1        a   foo  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000      cat
# 2        a   bar  1.3000000  0.1049383 17.66666667      dog
# 3        a   baz 31.0000000  0.1049383  1.66666667 elephant
# 4        b   foo  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000  dolphin
# 5        b   bar  2.7647059  1.5000000  0.02439024 chipmunk
# 6        b   baz 28.9705882 17.5000000  0.04559915   badger
# 7        c   foo  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000    tapir
# 8        c   bar  1.0000000  0.2473118  1.00000000   monkey
# 9        c   baz  0.9302326  0.5698925 22.26086957     duck
```

---

Just in case OP wanted to add these as new/additional columns and keep the previous data unchanged, you could modify the above approach to:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group_ID) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(./median(.[class == "foo"])), setNames(var1:var3, paste0("varN", 1:3)))
```

Comment: Thankyou, looks like it should do the trick. Not surprised there was a dplyr solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `data.table` solution.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'group_ID', we loop (with `lapply`) through a subset of columns that start with the column name 'var' (using `grep` we are subsetting), divide each column by the `median` of subset of that column that corresponds to the 'foo' value in 'class'.  This can be assigned (`:=`) as new column or we can assign it back to the same column to replace the original column.  One problem with replacing the original column is that we should match the `class` of the original with the replaced one.  If the original class of 'var' columns are `numeric`, then it will work as the `median` calculation and division converts the new columns to `numeric`.  A possible option if the original columns are `integer` class will be to change the class to `numeric` and then assign.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, paste0("varN", 1:3) := lapply(.SD[, 
     grep("^var", names(.SD)), with=FALSE], 
         function(x) x/median(x[class=="foo"])), group_ID]
df
# group_ID class  var1 var2 var3 metadata      varN1      varN2       varN3
#1:        a   foo   1.0  324    3      cat  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
#2:        a   bar   1.3   34   53      dog  1.3000000  0.1049383 17.66666667
#3:        a   baz  31.0   34    5 elephant 31.0000000  0.1049383  1.66666667
#4:        b   foo  34.0   34  943  dolphin  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
#5:        b   bar  94.0   51   23 chipmunk  2.7647059  1.5000000  0.02439024
#6:        b   baz 985.0  595   43   badger 28.9705882 17.5000000  0.04559915
#7:        c   foo  43.0   93   23    tapir  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
#8:        c   bar  43.0   23   23   monkey  1.0000000  0.2473118  1.00000000
#9:        c   baz  40.0   53  512     duck  0.9302326  0.5698925 22.26086957
```

Comment: @PierreLafortune  I forgot to use `.SD` with the `grep` earlier and was a bit busy with a meeting.

Comment: Think of it statistically. For several 100 upvotes you receive you get one downvote. Statistically insignificant. :)

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments.

Answer (score 4):

**1) by** Here is a base R solution:

```
do.call("rbind", by(DF, DF$group_ID, function(d)
      data.frame(d, sapply(d[3:5], function(x) x / median(x[d$class == "foo"])))
))
```

giving:

```
    group_ID class  var1 var2 var3 metadata     var1.1     var2.1      var3.1
a.1        a   foo   1.0  324    3      cat  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
a.2        a   bar   1.3   34   53      dog  1.3000000  0.1049383 17.66666667
a.3        a   baz  31.0   34    5 elephant 31.0000000  0.1049383  1.66666667
b.4        b   foo  34.0   34  943  dolphin  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
b.5        b   bar  94.0   51   23 chipmunk  2.7647059  1.5000000  0.02439024
b.6        b   baz 985.0  595   43   badger 28.9705882 17.5000000  0.04559915
c.7        c   foo  43.0   93   23    tapir  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
c.8        c   bar  43.0   23   23   monkey  1.0000000  0.2473118  1.00000000
c.9        c   baz  40.0   53  512     duck  0.9302326  0.5698925 22.26086957
```

**2) by/sweep** An alternative using `sweep` and, again, only base functions is:

```
do.call("rbind", by(DF, DF$group_ID, function(d) {
      med <- apply(subset(d, class == "foo")[3:5], 2, median)
      data.frame(d, sweep(as.matrix(d[3:5]), 2, med, "/"))
    }))
```

**3) sapply/ave** Yet another base solution is to apply `ave` to each of the `var` columns:

```
data.frame(DF, sapply(names(DF[3:5]), function(j)
    ave(1:nrow(DF), DF$group_ID, FUN = function(i)
        DF[i, j] / median(subset(DF[i, ], class == "foo")[[j]]))
))
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- structure(list(group_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), class = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("bar", "baz", "foo"
), class = "factor"), var1 = c(1, 1.3, 31, 34, 94, 985, 43, 43, 
40), var2 = c(324L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 51L, 595L, 93L, 23L, 53L), 
    var3 = c(3L, 53L, 5L, 943L, 23L, 43L, 23L, 23L, 512L), metadata = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c("badger", "cat", 
    "chipmunk", "dog", "dolphin", "duck", "elephant", "monkey", 
    "tapir"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("group_ID", "class", 
"var1", "var2", "var3", "metadata"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```